# Python 2: one-line or very compact code to check "startswith" across several strings?

Tags: python, list

The scenario:

I have a list:

```
['item','place','thing']
```

And I have some strings:

```
"item", "item1", "thing55", "place_C", "stuff", "junk5"
```

Of the above, I want the first four to match, and the last two to not match. The startswith function is most appropriate for this check.

(The list of test strings "item", "item1", etc. is not a python list; it's just a set of sample data that might be checked. However, the list of strings to match against "item","place","thing" IS a python list in code.)

I could iterate through the first list and compare the string with startswith:

```
successVar = False
for s in myStrings:
    if (testString.startswith(s)): 
        successVar = True
        break
#  Now you would check successVar to decide if string matched
```

But this doesn't necessarily work best in all cases. For example, suppose this is part of an if/elif structure:

```
if (testString == "hello"):
    # do something based on exact string match
elif (testString.endswith("!")):
    # do something if string ends with _one_ specific entity
elif <somehow, do the above comparison in here>
    # do something if string starts with any of the items in a list
else:
    # do something if string didn't match anything
```

I suppose I could wrap the entire check inside a function, but it feels to me like there might be a way to do this with inline code more easily or more concisely.

Is this even possible to do without making a function?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`str.startswith()` accepts a tuple of prefixes:

```
>>> "item1".startswith(("item","place","thing"))
True
```

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy: I think it's only tuples, not arbitrary iterables, to avoid having to check for recursion in the C code.

Comment: Yes, just now checked. So it must be string, or unicode or tuple.

Comment: `TypeError: startswith first arg must be str, unicode, or tuple, not list`

Comment: @nneonneo: It's trivial to get a tuple of strings formed from a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions for the various kinds of tests. It's easy for a regex to be "starts with," "ends with", "matches exactly", or "contains." You can even specify that the match should be case-insensitive. You can use a dictionary to associate the regular expressions with each action to be taken (which should be a function):

```
import re

def handle_item(text):
    print "handling item", text

def handle_place(text):
    print "handling place", text

def handle_thing(text):
    print "handling thing", text

match_dict = {"!$":          handle_thing,    # ends with !
              "(?i)^hello$": handle_place,    # case-insensitive exact match for hello
              "^@":          handle_item,     # begins with @
             }

test_string = raw_input("Enter a string to test: ")

for regex in match_dict:
    if re.search(test_string, regex):
        match_dict[regex](test_string)        # call function
        break
```

If the tests should be performed in a particular order, you can use a `collections.OrderedDict` to provide that (or a list of tuples, for that matter). Also, currently the testing stops after one match is found; if multiple tests could match, and you want them all to be handled, just remove the `break`.

Of course this just handles one item... I'd put this in a function and call it for each item, putting the splitting up of the items in a function of its own.

Comment: The OP asked for something *simpler* than the (working!) code he already has.

Comment: Yes, which is why I recommended using regexes: it allows the startswith/endswith/contains/matches behavior to be put in the data, so instead of a tower of `if` statements you just need a 3 or 4 line loop.

Comment: I see. So you're giving the OP what you think they really need rather than what they explicitly asked for. Which isn't always a bad thing. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Could use `csv` to break up your string, and then just pass a `tuple` to `str.startswith`:

```
import csv

check = ['item','place','thing']
items = '"item", "item1", "thing55", "place_C", "stuff", "junk5"'
match = [el for el in next(csv.reader([items], skipinitialspace=True)) if el.startswith(tuple(check))]
# ['item', 'item1', 'thing55', 'place_C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the list of allowed prefixes into a string, separated by `|`, such as:

```
pattern = "|".join(['item','place','thing'])
```

Then use `re.match()`:

```
strs = ["item", "item1", "thing55", "place_C", "stuff", "junk5"]
matching_strs = [s for s in strs if re.match(pattern, s)]
```

This produces:

```
matching_strs
=> ['item', 'item1', 'thing55', 'place_C']
```

This should be faster, also, then the other methods suggested, since it will look into any string in `strs` only once, and compare it against all allowed prefixes "at once", instead of one at a time.

You can even make it faster if you use `re.compile` on `pattern`.

Caveat: this simple case will work only if the allowed prefixes do not contain "special" characters (in the `re` sense), such as `|`, `.`, `(`, etc. If they do, you'll have to escape them first before joining them with `|`.